# Double steel king

Tags: kings

For a few examples of a [king walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_walk), see Tim Krabbe's site. Do you have an example where *both* kings go haywire? (Found this own game in my old chess zines, but since the heavy material is just a Q plus a N resp. B, I can at most dub that "bronze kings" - those posers were never in danger, so I guess at least Q+R should be present. But see:)

```
[FEN ""]

1. Nf3 c5 2. d4 cxd4 3. Nxd4 Nf6 4. c4 Nc6 5. Nc3 g6 6. e4 d6 7. Be2 Bg7 8. Be3 O-O 9. O-O Be6 10. f3 Qa5 11. Qd2 Rac8 12. b3 Nxd4 13. Bxd4 a6 14. Rfd1 Qh5 15. Nd5 Bxd5 16. cxd5 Nd7 17. Rac1 Bxd4+ 18. Qxd4 Qg5 19. Rxc8 Rxc8 20. Qd2 Qe5 21. Rc1 Rxc1+ 22. Qxc1 Qd4+ 23. Kf1 Nc5 24. Qc2 b5 25. g3 Kg7 26. Kg2 b4 27. Bc4 a5 28. Bb5 g5 29. Qc1 Kf6 30. h4 h6 31. hxg5+ hxg5 32. Qc2 Ke5 33. Qe2 Qc3 34. Kh3 Qc1 35. Kg4 Kd4 36. Kh3 Kc3 37. Kg4 f6 38. Kf5 Qc2 39. Qc4+ Kb2 40. Qxc2+ Kxc2 41. Kg6 Kb2 42. Bc4 Kxa2 43. Kf7 g4 44. fxg4 Nxe4 45. Kxe7 Kb2 46. Ke6 Kc3 47. Kf5 a4 48. Kxe4 a3 49. Kf5 a2 50. Kxf6 a1=Q 51. g5 Qa8 52. Ke7 Qg8 53. Kxd6 Qxg5 54. Kd7 Kd4 55. d6 Kc5 56. Kc7 Qxg3 0-1
```